# Check runtime type of List<Model> as List<dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart

Actually I was doing a condition check inorder to find the data type of a variable. But when comes to List type check. there's a issue like "List of Model != List of dynamic"

```
bool nullEmptyChk(dynamic val) {
bool rtnVal = false;
try {
  switch (val.runtimeType) {
    case List:
      rtnVal = (val == null || val.isEmpty);
      break;
    case String:
      rtnVal = (val == null || val.isEmpty);
      break;
    default:
      rtnVal = (val == null);
  }
} catch (e) {
  rtnVal = false;
}

return rtnVal;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for this instead;

```
if (val is List?) {
  rtnVal = (val == null || val.isEmpty);
}
```

Sadly the `is` keyword doesn't work in `switch` statements so you'll have to rewrite it to `if` statements then. Although it seems like it might be possible in the future because the developers announced changes for Dart 3.0 that makes switches much more powerful. See https://youtu.be/KhYTFglbF2k?t=620 if you're interested